# Moving camera "flat", ignoring it's x and z rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The scenario is as follows - user can click on a character to make the main camera look at that selected character, using this code:

```
private void RotateTowardsCharacter() {
     RaycastHit hit;
     var cameraCenter = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));

     if (Physics.Raycast(cameraCenter, transform.forward, out hit, 1000)) {
         var obj = hit.transform.gameObject;

         if (obj == _activeCharacter) {    
             return;
         }
     }

     var relativePos = _activeCharacter.transform.position - transform.position;
     var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos.normalized);
     var rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime);

     transform.rotation = rotation;
 }
```

I also want to enable camera movement using WSAD (or arrows) keys, so I created this code:

```
 private void MoveCamera() {
     var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 20;
     var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 20;

     if (x == 0 && z == 0) {
         return;
     }

     transform.Translate(x, 0, z, Space.Self);
 }
```

You may see the problem already - if the camera is rotated on the X axis, then pressing the W key will actually make camera zoom on whatever it's pointing at. 
Now, what I want to achieve:

Imagine you're walking on a street, head down, looking at your iPhone - even though your head is rotated on the X axis, you move forward along the pavement - not getting closer to the ground which would just be weird :). If you tilt your head a bit around the Z axis, you'll be still walking straight, so actually the one thing that is affecting your movement direction is your body's rotation around the Y axis.

And that's what I want to achieve - I want to move the camera on a plane that's at the height of it's current Y coord, forwards or backwards, left or right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code did the trick:

```
private void MoveForwardFlat(float z) {
    var fwd = transform.forward;

    fwd.y = 0;

    fwd.Normalize();

    if (fwd != Vector3.zero) {
        transform.position += fwd * z;
    }
}
```

It also makes sure that the movement speed will be constant despite the rotation.

Answer (score 1):

## Vector Math is amazing

By multiplying your input by the `Transform.forward` and `Transform.right` values, you can get relative direction vectors, which you can then add together to get a final translation vector.

```
private void MoveCamera() {
     Vector3 horiz = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 20 * transform.right;
     Vector3 forward = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 20 * transform.forward;

     if ((horiz + forward).sqrMagnitude < 0.01f) {
         return;
     }

     transform.Translate(horiz + forward, Space.Self);
}
```

Comment: This gives me weird results. If the camera is rotated on each axis then moving left or right actually moves the camera left or right but also impacts the Y coord of the camera, so it moves it also slightly up or down.

Comment: The effect I'm after can be expressed by the method `Vector3.ProjectOnPlane` (and also my solution below).

Comment: Left-right movement should only ever move the camera on the Y axis if it has been rotated around its Z axis, which you should never want to do. You'll get forward-backward Y axis movement if its been rotated on the X axis...but your own answer would have that problem as well.

Comment: I fixed my rotation code to prevent from rotating on the Z axis, but I still have the mentioned issue.

Comment: @MarekM. To which I say, "it is unclear what you're asking." You want the camera to move in a rotated space without the move being subject to the rotation.

Comment: I've updated my question. Hopefully, with this metaphore it will be clearer now :)

Answer (score -1):

THE EASY WAY! NO CODE NEEDED!
create an EMPTY OBJECT with global gizmo and attach the camera as a child. then attach the movement code to the father empty object.
now the code follows the (0, 0, 0) transform of the empty object and the camera follow him as a child.

had the same problem and I wanted to solve it without coding